# Cockroachdb used all memory after start even though data size is only 2GiB

Tags: cockroachdb

1. 1.9 GiB database size on disk.
2. 60 GiB memory.

[image]

After start cockroach starts to use all memory and increase goroutines count, until it eats whole memory.

```
gossip client (0/3 cur/max conns)
gossip server (0/3 cur/max conns, infos 0/0 sent/received, bytes 0B/0B sent/received)
W200117 11:21:26.697551 195 storage/store.go:3926  [n1,s1] handle raft ready: 0.6s [processed=1]
W200117 11:21:26.839611 177 storage/store.go:3926  [n1,s1] handle raft ready: 0.6s [processed=1]
W200117 11:21:26.839933 206 storage/store.go:3926  [n1,s1] handle raft ready: 0.7s [processed=1]
W200117 11:21:26.840083 170 storage/store.go:3926  [n1,s1] handle raft ready: 0.6s [processed=1]
W200117 11:21:27.036814 190 storage/store.go:3926  [n1,s1] handle raft ready: 0.6s [processed=1]
W200117 11:21:29.764620 198 storage/store.go:3926  [n1,s1] handle raft ready: 0.7s [processed=1]
W200117 11:21:34.446099 167 storage/store.go:3926  [n1,s1] handle raft ready: 0.7s [processed=1]
W200117 11:21:34.563275 182 storage/store.go:3926  [n1,s1] handle raft ready: 1.0s [processed=1]
I200117 11:21:35.034645 276 server/status/runtime.go:465  [n1] runtime stats: 60 GiB RSS, 9012 goroutines, 52 GiB/3.6 GiB/59 GiB GO alloc/idle/total, 761 MiB/852 MiB CGO alloc/total, 11145.7 CGO/sec, 732.2/48.3 %(u/s)time, 0.1 %gc (1x), 411 KiB/571 KiB (r/w)net
W200117 11:21:36.774832 170 storage/store.go:3926  [n1,s1] handle raft ready: 0.7s [processed=1]
I200117 11:21:45.128897 276 server/status/runtime.go:465  [n1] runtime stats: 61 GiB RSS, 9111 goroutines, 53 GiB/4.0 GiB/60 GiB GO alloc/idle/total, 445 MiB/539 MiB CGO alloc/total, 23047.0 CGO/sec, 754.2/28.9 %(u/s)time, 0.0 %gc (0x), 362 KiB/455 KiB (r/w)net
fatal error: runtime: out of memory
```

After that there are only errors in log:

```
runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x2b00eec, 0x16)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:616 +0x81
runtime.sysMap(0xd2d44b0000, 0x2db0000, 0x0, 0x4882bf8)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mem_linux.go:216 +0x20a
runtime.(*mheap).sysAlloc(0x48410a0, 0x2db0000, 0x20224af01)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:470 +0xd4
runtime.(*mheap).grow(0x48410a0, 0x16d7, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:907 +0x60
runtime.(*mheap).allocSpanLocked(0x48410a0, 0x16d7, 0x4882c08, 0x2050e5e)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:820 +0x301
runtime.(*mheap).alloc_m(0x48410a0, 0x16d7, 0x101, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:686 +0x118
runtime.(*mheap).alloc.func1()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:753 +0x4d
runtime.(*mheap).alloc(0x48410a0, 0x16d7, 0xd00f000101, 0xc4204a4180)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:752 +0x8a
runtime.largeAlloc(0x2dae000, 0xd00f970100, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:826 +0x94
runtime.mallocgc.func1()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:721 +0x46
runtime.systemstack(0x7f1b00000000)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:409 +0x79
runtime.mstart()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1175

goroutine 16380 [running]:
runtime.systemstack_switch()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:363 fp=0xc9995451b8 sp=0xc9995451b0 pc=0x70b970
runtime.mallocgc(0x2dae000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:720 +0x8a2 fp=0xc999545258 sp=0xc9995451b8 pc=0x6c46e2
runtime.growslice(0x268d940, 0xd29e7c0000, 0xd146e4, 0xd146e4, 0x2dad295, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/slice.go:172 +0x21d fp=0xc9995452c0 sp=0xc999545258 pc=0x6f5c2d
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/roachpb.(*ScanResponse).combine(0xd064b26ee8, 0x302bdc0, 0xd0bc2462b0, 0x302bdc0, 0xd0bc2462b0)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/roachpb/api.go:259 +0x3fb fp=0xc9995453e0 sp=0xc9995452c0 pc=0xda0efb
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/roachpb.(*BatchResponse).Combine(0xcae57fb7a0, 0xc503e11da0, 0xc7b2972a40, 0x6, 0x8, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/roachpb/batch.go:360 +0x32e fp=0xc9995454c8 sp=0xc9995453e0 pc=0xe4d50e
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv.(*DistSender).divideAndSendBatchToRanges.func1(0xc999545848, 0xc999545b28, 0xc999545a70, 0xc999545b20, 0xc99954578f, 0xc999545830, 0xc999545794)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv/dist_sender.go:821 +0x273 fp=0xc999545680 sp=0xc9995454c8 pc=0x1767443
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv.(*DistSender).divideAndSendBatchToRanges(0xc42077a700, 0x305a3c0, 0xcb14dc0d20, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc4de731900, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv/dist_sender.go:1000 +0x797 fp=0xc999545a58 sp=0xc999545680 pc=0x174b557
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv.(*DistSender).Send(0xc42077a700, 0x305a3c0, 0xcb14dc0d20, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc67b3dbd00, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv/dist_sender.go:683 +0x4c7 fp=0xc999545d58 sp=0xc999545a58 pc=0x174a497
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv.(*txnLockGatekeeper).SendLocked(0xcb19e3abc8, 0x305a3c0, 0xcb14dc0d20, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc67b3dbd00, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv/txn_coord_sender.go:234 +0xf5 fp=0xc999545e08 sp=0xc999545d58 pc=0x17588a5
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv.(*txnMetrics).SendLocked(0xcb19e3ab90, 0x305a3c0, 0xcb14dc0d20, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc67b3dbd00, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv/txn_interceptor_metrics.go:58 +0x12d fp=0xc999545ed8 sp=0xc999545e08 pc=0x1761f7d
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv.(*txnSpanRefresher).sendLockedWithRefreshAttempts(0xcb19e3aaf8, 0x305a3c0, 0xcb14dc0d20, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc67b3dbd00, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv/txn_interceptor_span_refresher.go:167 +0x98 fp=0xc999545fb8 sp=0xc999545ed8 pc=0x17645a8
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv.(*txnSpanRefresher).SendLocked(0xcb19e3aaf8, 0x305a3c0, 0xcb14dc0d20, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc67b3dbd00, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv/txn_interceptor_span_refresher.go:105 +0x11e fp=0xc9995460a0 sp=0xc999545fb8 pc=0x176404e
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv.(*txnPipeliner).SendLocked(0xcb19e3aa78, 0x305a3c0, 0xcb14dc0d20, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc67b3dbd00, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv/txn_interceptor_pipeliner.go:169 +0x165 fp=0xc9995461b8 sp=0xc9995460a0 pc=0x1762555
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv.(*txnIntentCollector).SendLocked(0xcb19e3aa38, 0x305a3c0, 0xcb14dc0d20, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc67b3dbd00, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv/txn_interceptor_intent_collector.go:106 +0x45d fp=0xc999546338 sp=0xc9995461b8 pc=0x17605ad
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv.(*txnSeqNumAllocator).SendLocked(0xcb19e3ab78, 0x305a3c0, 0xcb14dc0d20, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc67b3dbd00, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv/txn_interceptor_sequence_nums.go:62 +0x1f3 fp=0xc999546450 sp=0xc999546338 pc=0x1763e33
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv.(*txnHeartbeat).SendLocked(0xcb19e3a990, 0x305a3c0, 0xcb14dc0d20, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc67b3dbd00, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv/txn_interceptor_heartbeat.go:230 +0x542 fp=0xc999546e00 sp=0xc999546450 pc=0x175df82
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv.(*TxnCoordSender).Send(0xcb19e3a800, 0x305a3c0, 0xcb14dc0d20, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc67b3dbd00, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/kv/txn_coord_sender.go:648 +0x456 fp=0xc999547160 sp=0xc999546e00 pc=0x175b136
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/internal/client.(*DB).sendUsingSender(0xc420778280, 0x305a3c0, 0xc9d8025380, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/internal/client/db.go:623 +0x135 fp=0xc999547228 sp=0xc999547160 pc=0xfdc3f5
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/internal/client.(*Txn).Send(0xc909d72990, 0x305a3c0, 0xc9d8025380, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/internal/client/txn.go:805 +0x14c fp=0xc999547380 sp=0xc999547228 pc=0xfe64ac
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/sqlbase.(*txnKVFetcher).fetch(0xc6b75efd50, 0x305a3c0, 0xc9d8025380, 0x0, 0xc9995479c0)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/sqlbase/kvfetcher.go:327 +0x597 fp=0xc9995477f8 sp=0xc999547380 pc=0x15708a7
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/sqlbase.(*txnKVFetcher).nextBatch(0xc6b75efd50, 0x305a3c0, 0xc9d8025380, 0x10000cc88b49400, 0x0, 0x15, 0xcc88b49420, 0x0, 0xc42b83d400, 0x2, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/sqlbase/kvfetcher.go:394 +0x6d fp=0xc999547878 sp=0xc9995477f8 pc=0x157112d
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/sqlbase.(*RowFetcher).nextKV(0xcad73e5f18, 0x305a3c0, 0xc9d8025380, 0x3f, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/sqlbase/rowfetcher.go:479 +0x370 fp=0xc999547a20 sp=0xc999547878 pc=0x157a730
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/sqlbase.(*RowFetcher).NextKey(0xcad73e5f18, 0x305a3c0, 0xc9d8025380, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/sqlbase/rowfetcher.go:498 +0x8a fp=0xc999547b00 sp=0xc999547a20 pc=0x157a9da
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/sqlbase.(*RowFetcher).StartScanFrom(0xcad73e5f18, 0x305a3c0, 0xc9d8025380, 0x30387c0, 0xc6b75efd50, 0x0, 0x1)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/sqlbase/rowfetcher.go:447 +0xd9 fp=0xc999547b40 sp=0xc999547b00 pc=0x157a359
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/sqlbase.(*RowFetcher).StartScan(0xcad73e5f18, 0x305a3c0, 0xc9d8025380, 0xc909d72990, 0xc9f8754400, 0x3f, 0x40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/sqlbase/rowfetcher.go:435 +0x208 fp=0xc999547c88 sp=0xc999547b40 pc=0x157a1c8
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/distsqlrun.(*joinReader).readInput(0xcad73e5500, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/distsqlrun/joinreader.go:440 +0x92c fp=0xc999547e38 sp=0xc999547c88 pc=0x17c8b3c
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/distsqlrun.(*joinReader).Next(0xcad73e5500, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xcb15328e10)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/distsqlrun/joinreader.go:356 +0x2df fp=0xc999547e90 sp=0xc999547e38 pc=0x17c81af
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/distsqlrun.Run(0x305a3c0, 0xc9d8025380, 0x3063380, 0xcad73e5500, 0x3037440, 0xcb19e92e00)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/distsqlrun/base.go:172 +0x35 fp=0xc999547ed0 sp=0xc999547e90 pc=0x1789045
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/distsqlrun.(*ProcessorBase).Run(0xcad73e5500, 0x305a3c0, 0xc9d8025380, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/distsqlrun/processors.go:731 +0x98 fp=0xc999547f10 sp=0xc999547ed0 pc=0x17d4b58
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/distsqlrun.(*Flow).StartSync(0xcad736dc00, 0x305a3c0, 0xc9d8025380, 0x2c375e8, 0xcad72389a0, 0x3037140)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/distsqlrun/flow.go:581 +0x191 fp=0xc999547f60 sp=0xc999547f10 pc=0x17aaa41
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql.(*DistSQLPlanner).Run(0xc4208e7700, 0xc4c10cb020, 0xc909d72360, 0xc999548898, 0xcb19e8a500, 0xc8e49839b0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/distsql_running.go:253 +0x886 fp=0xc999548790 sp=0xc999547f60 pc=0x1b119a6
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql.(*DistSQLPlanner).PlanAndRun(0xc4208e7700, 0x305a3c0, 0xc9d8024b10, 0xc8e49839b0, 0xc4c10cb020, 0xc909d72360, 0x304d340, 0xcad73ecdc0, 0xcb19e8a500)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/distsql_running.go:756 +0x24c fp=0xc999548a38 sp=0xc999548790 pc=0x1b14fac
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql.(*connExecutor).execWithDistSQLEngine(0xc8e4983500, 0x305a3c0, 0xc9d8024b10, 0xc8e4983918, 0x3, 0x7f1b1a3c03c0, 0xc909d72480, 0xcabe553601, 0xd, 0xd)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/conn_executor_exec.go:971 +0x2d8 fp=0xc999548c10 sp=0xc999548a38 pc=0x1ac15d8
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql.(*connExecutor).dispatchToExecutionEngine(0xc8e4983500, 0x305a3c0, 0xc9d8024b10, 0x305da40, 0xcafa482f80, 0xcabe553680, 0xd, 0xd, 0xc90a26f440, 0x119, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/conn_executor_exec.go:818 +0xa7e fp=0xc999548dd8 sp=0xc999548c10 pc=0x1ac096e
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql.(*connExecutor).execStmtInOpenState(0xc8e4983500, 0x305a3c0, 0xc9d8024b10, 0x305da40, 0xcafa482f80, 0xcabe553680, 0xd, 0xd, 0xc90a26f440, 0x119, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/conn_executor_exec.go:396 +0xa8f fp=0xc9995495b0 sp=0xc999548dd8 pc=0x1abc96f
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql.(*connExecutor).execStmt(0xc8e4983500, 0x305a3c0, 0xc9d8024b10, 0x305da40, 0xcafa482f80, 0xcabe553680, 0xd, 0xd, 0xc90a26f440, 0x119, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/conn_executor_exec.go:96 +0x341 fp=0xc999549748 sp=0xc9995495b0 pc=0x1abbac1
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql.(*connExecutor).run(0xc8e4983500, 0x305a300, 0xc9e1391740, 0xc4207bee58, 0x5400, 0x15000, 0xc4207beef0, 0xc4c0d0c790, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/conn_executor.go:1180 +0x1400 fp=0xc999549e88 sp=0xc999549748 pc=0x1ab3560
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql.(*Server).ServeConn(0xc42087e780, 0x305a300, 0xc9e1391740, 0xc8e4983500, 0x5400, 0x15000, 0xc4207beef0, 0xc4c0d0c790, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/conn_executor.go:391 +0xce fp=0xc999549ee8 sp=0xc999549e88 pc=0x1aaf1de
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/pgwire.(*conn).processCommandsAsync.func1(0xc66dbb98c1, 0xc719da4640, 0x305a300, 0xc9e1391740, 0xc4c0d0c790, 0x304f900, 0xc719da4620, 0xc9c20116e0, 0xc426828a00, 0x0, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/pgwire/conn.go:520 +0x1e7 fp=0xc999549f78 sp=0xc999549ee8 pc=0x1f07747
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361 +0x1 fp=0xc999549f80 sp=0xc999549f78 pc=0x70e501
created by github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/pgwire.(*conn).processCommandsAsync
    /go/src/github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pkg/sql/pgwire/conn.go:475 +0x17b
```

I've used this config `max-sql-memory=.3` and `cache=.40`.

Answer (score 1):

From the `handle raft ready` messages, it seems like your disk is underprovisioned on IOPS or slow to handle requests, which is causing KV operations to queue up in memory.

One workaround to physically limit the amount of memory Cockroach's SQL processors and storage-level caches use, using the flags `--max-sql-memory` and `--cache` respectively. This will not solve this problem entirely as raft operations will still queue up until the disk is correctly provisioned, but it will help.

The below command will set both SQL and cache memory limits to 25% of total system memory:

`cockroach start --store=<dir> --max-sql-memory=0.25 --cache=0.25`

More on memory limits: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/memory-usage-cockroachdb/

Comment: I've used `max-sql-memory=.3` and `cache=.40`. It didn't help.